# Perl Date::Manip detects timezone wrong for EST and EDT

Tags: perl, datetime, date-manipulation

I have the server where system timezone is EST

It was set with

```
# timedatectl set-timezone EST
# timedatectl 
  Local time: Tue 2019-06-18 03:29:42 EST
  Universal time: Tue 2019-06-18 08:29:42 UTC
    RTC time: Tue 2019-06-18 08:29:42
    Time zone: EST (EST, -0500)
    NTP enabled: yes
    NTP synchronized: no
    RTC in local TZ: no
    DST active: n/a
```

Then in my **perl** code i try to detect timezone and convert time to UTC
And for some reason, a timezone is detected as EDT. Currently (summer) EST is one our after EDT

My perl code is

```
# cat test.cgi # code file is named test.cgi
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Date::Manip;

print "Local time: ".UnixDate("now","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")."\n";

# get local system timezone
my $TZ = UnixDate("now","%Z");

# convert time to GMT 
my $dtlocal =  Date_ConvTZ(ParseDate(UnixDate("now","%g")),$TZ,"GMT");

# format GMT time
my $dt =  UnixDate($dtlocal,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); 

print "Timezone: $TZ\n";
print "UTC time: $dt\n";
```

And i execute the script

```
# date
Tue Jun 18 04:17:56 EST 2019
# date -u
Tue Jun 18 09:17:58 UTC 2019
# ./test.cgi 
Local time: 2019-06-18 04:18:00 EDT
Timezone: EDT
UTC time: 2019-06-18 08:18:00
```

What can be the reason that Date::Manip detects timezone wrongly? 
Is there other good way to detect system timezone?

UPDATE.

I have just found that POSIX detects timezone correctly. So, the problem is with Date::Manip

```
 use POSIX;
 print strftime("%Z", localtime()), "\n";
```

Comment: I wasn't quickly able to find where exactly Date::Manip makes its decision of whether you're on standard time or DST, but the US changed its start/end dates for DST in 2007. Is it possible that your Date::Manip might be old enough to still be using the old start/end dates instead of the current ones?

Comment: I have the version 6.54 , according to their docs it is from 2016-05-31 . https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Date-Manip

Comment: I've run your code using the latest version of Date::Manip (6.77) and I'm still seeing the same, incorrect, behaviour. I suggest [reporting it as a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Date-Manip).

Comment: It's important to remember that EST and EDT are not fully realized time zones. They are offsets. The time zone is America/New_York (or the appropriate locale). This is how you can have a winter datetime and a summer datetime in the same timezone with a different offset. So the "decision" whether DST is in effect depends on both the timezone and the datetime in question.

Comment: Therefore it sounds like Date::Manip is trying to be too clever, and assuming that all EST time zones are America/New_York.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the time zone is with [DateTime::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone). Used with [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) for other needs

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime; 
use DateTime::TimeZone; 

my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => "local");
say $tz->name();                                   #--> America/Los_Angeles


my $dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => "local");
say "local: $dt";                             #--> local: 2019-06-18T09:57:58

$dt->set_time_zone("UTC"); 
say "UTC: $dt";                               #--> UTC: 2019-06-18T16:57:58
```

Please see documentation for details, at least for the [DateTime::TimeZone constructor](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone#DateTime::TimeZone-%3Enew(-name-=%3E-$tz_name-)).

Also note their recommendation to *not* use "short" names ("EST"), under [$tz->short_name...](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone#$tz-%3Eshort_name_for_datetime(-$dt-))

---

Once you are working with `DateTime` can also have offset

```
my $dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local');

say $dt->offset/(60*60);                       #--> -7

say $dt->strftime("%z");                       #--> -0700
```

The method [offset](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Eoffset()) returns the time-zone offset in seconds.

The [strftime](https://metacpan.or/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Estrftime(-$format,-...-)) offer formats we normally expect; docs say "*any deviation from the POSIX standard is probably a bug.*" A full timestamp example: `$dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')`.

Answer (score 2):

The Date::Manip::TZ documentation has a section on [Determining the System Time Zone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip::TZ#DETERMINING-THE-SYSTEM-TIME-ZONE).  If you scroll down a bit, you will find a list of which methods are used (and in what order) to determine the system time zone, depending on whether you're running under Unix or Windows.

Based on what you've posted in the question, it appears to be reading the local time correctly, but failing to identify the right time zone, so you should be able to find the root problem by going down the list of TZ identification methods used on your OS.  (i.e., for Unix, check `$::TZ`, then the `zone` and `TZ` environment settings, then `/etc/TIMEZONE`, etc. until you find one that both exists and has the wrong timezone listed)